# How I can combine variables as matrix in R Language

Tags: r, matrix

I have generated six standard normal variable using following  code in R

```
     for(i in 1:6){
     assign(paste("x", i, sep = ""), rnorm(1000,0,1)))
     }
```

when i enter x1, x2, ... x6 etc at command prompt I got the values.

I require to save these variables as matrix.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `matrix`

```
for(i in 1:6){
  assign(paste("x", i, sep = ""), matrix(rnorm(1000,0,1), ncol=10))
}
```

see `?matrix` for further details. I don't know the dimension of the matrix you want to get, I used a 100 x 10 to illustrate the code.

With your current code, you are assigning 1000 random values from a standard normal distribution to each vector `x1, x2, ..., x6`, you need to add `matrix` and specify either the number of columns or rows for the desired matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your help and guidance all

Answer (score 3):

```
matrix(rnorm(6000,0,1),nrow=1000,ncol=6)
```